# Android: Sending app updates to remote clients without wiping their data

Tags: android, sqlite, android-keystore, app-update

Interesting technical problem here; I have done a little bit of digging and haven't been able to find someone in a comparable situation.

I'm working on an app project for researchers at a couple different universities, and the app needs a couple updates to fix a bug they are having, but they don't want to lose any of the data they have already accumulated with the app (its a SQLite database that's storing results); problem is the only way for me to install updates without wiping the app data is in person; when I try to export a signed APK, put it on my tablet, and tried to install it, it prompted me to just install the update without wiping the app, but after saying yes and allowing it to install it just says "app is not installed". I can only update the app successfully if I have my tablet connected up to my computer and run the app from within android studio.

The app has been using the same key store file, which I thought meant there wouldn't be any problems relating to different keys.

I've verified that the proper permissions are set; obviously, I could just uninstall the app and install it with the new apk, but that defeats the purpose.

My first question is, does anyone know how someone could update (not reinstall!) an app they have using an apk file recieved from an email, *without wiping any of the data on that tablet?*

I don't have any experience with the app store but from what I know about the app store my app wouldn't pass their qualifications so I can't use that as a platform to deploy updates to my user. Does anyone have any insights on this?

Thanks!

Comment: "when I try to export a signed APK, put it on my tablet, and tried to install it, it prompted me to just install the update without wiping the app, but after saying yes and allowing it to install it just says "app is not installed"" -- I suspect that the existing installed app and the APK are signed with different signing keys.

Comment: @CommonsWare That occurred to me, but I've been using the same keystore the entire time when I go to "Generate Signed APK". I've generated over a dozen versions of the app for my users to have using that keystore; is the keystore file distinct from the signing key? And if so, how can I recover the currently in-use versions apk to use with the old one?

Comment: "but I've been using the same keystore the entire time" -- perhaps for `release` builds. "put it on my tablet" -- perhaps your tablet has a `debug` build installed, not a `release` build. "is the keystore file distinct from the signing key?" -- the signing keys are in a keystore file. "how can I recover the currently in-use versions apk to use with the old one?" -- I do not know what you mean by this, sorry.